# Consider the permutation S = (1 2 3)(2 4 5). Determine the smallest positive integer n so that it S represents the identity permutation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. I don't know what the identity permutation is.

Secondly, I have the solution, but am not understanding the solution. It says to express it as a disjoint cycle and consider that S = (1 2 4 5 3) which I am not sure how they got that. I understand that they eventually have to take powers, but I do not understand how you get S = (1 2 4 5 3) from S = (1 2 3)(2 4 5).

Comment: I think there is something wrong in the title.  $S$ is a permutation, not a positive integer.

Comment: Sorry that's supposed to be n. But I know that's just whatever power it is to.

Comment: You do not get $(12345)$ from $(123)(245)$. You have $(123)(245)=(12453)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity permutation maps $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $2$, $3$ to $3$, $4$ to $4$, and $5$ to $5$.

The permutation $(245)$ maps $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $4$, $3$ to $3$, $4$ to $5$, and $5$ to $2$.

The permutation $(123)$ maps $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $1$, $4$ to $4$, and $5$ to $5$.

The composition $(123)(245)$ therefore maps $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $4$, $3$ to $1$, $4$ to $5$, and $5$ to $3$;
i.e., it's $(12453)$.

Since it's a $5$-cycle, its fifth power is $1$; i.e., the answer to the question in the title is $n=5$.

Answer (score 0):

$(1\ 2\ 3)(2\ 4\ 5)$ is the permutation that results from first performing $(2\ 4\ 5)$ and then performing $(1\ 2\ 3)$.  Functional composition, in other words.  The first permutation sends $2$ to $4$; the second leaves $4$ fixed, so the composition sends $2$ to $4$.  The first permutation sends $5$ to $2$ and the second sends $2$ to $3$ so the composition sends $5$ to $3$.

As to the identity permutation, it's the identity function -- it doesn't permute any elements.

Comment: So what about 1? From your explanation you just have (2 4 5 3)

Comment: The first permutation leaves $1$ fixed.  The second maps it to $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the elements in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and the images by the composition one after the other:

- $1\mapsto 1\mapsto2$, so the composition maps $\color{red}{1\mapsto 2}$.
- $2\mapsto4\mapsto 4$, so the composition maps  $\color{red}{1\mapsto 2\mapsto 4}$.
- $4\mapsto 5\mapsto 5$, so the composition maps  $\color{red}{1\mapsto 2\mapsto 4\mapsto 5}$.

&c.